# Sencha Architect erroneous ExtJS code

Tags: javascript, extjs

I created a new Sencha Architect project of type "Navigation", added a top panel, made some minor changes (remove some label, add an image), and saved. Now, the saved project has no working navigation, but instead, a JavaScript error occurs.

Firefox: `TypeError: Ext.history is undefined`

Chrome: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'init' of undefined`

So it seems like a library containing `Ext.history` has to be added, but how do I achieve this in Sencha Architect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [Ext.util.History](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.util.History) you can just add that as a "requires" dependency on your view, application, or any class in the app.

Comment: My Sencha architect generated code explicitly calls `Ext.History.init()`

Comment: Let me note that the missing lib is a bug in the actual stable release of sencha architect, which will be fixed in next release; and that adding the missing dependency is done in the properties window on the right side.